# Google Maps Application doesn't start anymore

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-drive-api

My map worked fine until recently. The HTML is using a javascript and css file loaded from Google Drive to display. It seems that this is the problem, because when I load these files directly from the computer, it works. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Atlas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBkcSHRlpwYgUpLlFXSC4hC73QCCcKNh2Q&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&language=ro"></script>
    <script src="http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/harta.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="elevation_chart"></div>
    <div id="legenda"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  there is no </div> for the element with id="elevation_chart".

Comment: I also get `GET http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/style.css 503 (Service Unavailable)`, and `GET http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/harta.js 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Comment: Modified it, but I have the same problem

Comment: Any ideas why those services are unavailable?

Comment: Ask Google (it is their server). Wasn't saying invalid HTML was the problem, but invalid HTML is never good.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have correct URL of your style.css file and harta.js files? As I can see these files don't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a universal problem with public-hosted html files hosted on Google Drive on 9/17. They were aware of the problem and as of today have fixed the issue.

If your map still doesn't work, try uploading your index.html file to the Drive, delete the old one, and refresh. That worked for me this morning.

See this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/tjqbzi61zIU/djTNxZ0i3C0J) from Google Groups on the issue.

Also, as of Monday, Google has reported several issues with Drive on it's [Apps Status Dashboard](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=e3ea8b21ee6bba558c13a8f8bd52a58a).